# How does int[int*] work in cpp? what is it's output?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int a[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
int*p=a;
cout<<4[p];
return 0;
```

can anyone please tell me how it is giving output 5. i know it is 5 because it is the 4th element in the array. but why is 4[p] giving the output!

Comment: `4[p]` is equivalent to `p[4]`.  Does that help?

Comment: `p[4]` just means `*(p+4)`, so `4[p]` just means `*(4+p)`